# Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn buttons with this functionality

Tags: facebook, twitter, linkedin

Is there a Twitter button that I can put on my site with the following functionality:

When the user clicks the button, it brings up a popup of my page on Twitter without the user leaving my site?

Is there also a Facebook button with this functionality?

And is there a LinkedIn button with this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put there is not generic button ready for anyone to grab a little bit of code for either facebook or twitter

For Twitter this is possible with the [Twitter @anywhere Platform](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere). this does involve a bit of coding. (not much)

I do not know about a way to do this through facebook or linked-in. but I assume it is not as easy as a pre-coded button

Answer (score 0):

you can user following code for do this..

```
 <!-- facebook -->
      <script>function fbs_click() {u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open(‘http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=’+encodeURIComponent(u)+’&t=’+encodeURIComponent(t),’sharer’,'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436′);return false;}</script><a href=”http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<url>” onclick=”return fbs_click()” target=”_blank”><img src=”ADD_IMAGE_URL_HERE” alt=”Share on Facebook” /></a>

      <!-- twitter -->
      <a href=”http://twitter.com/home?status=Currentlyreading <?php the_permalink(); ?>” title=”Click to share this post on Twitter”"><img src=”ADD_IMAGE_URL_HERE” alt=”Share on Twitter”></a>

<!-- Linkedin -->
<a href=”http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?phpthe_permalink(); ?>&title=<?php the_title(); ?>&source=ADD_YOUR_BLOG_URL_HERE”><img src=”ADD_IMAGE_URL_HERE”></a>
```

its may what you needed..

Thanks..

Comment: this by it self will **Not** bring up a popup but this could be used in conjunction I guess

Comment: ok..i have been edited my code.now you can check it out..thx.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.URL.com/" target="_blank">TITLE</a>
```

By including the 'target' property in the url, with a value of '_blank', your button will open in a new window.

If you want your button to have a certain look, you need to create an image in html that links to your social media pages.